# Django CORS denying access even though I've set CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

Tags: django, cors, django-cors-headers

I've got 2 separate projects and `project A` needs to access some things from `project B`. I've already installed CORS on `project B` but accessing its resources from `project A` still raises the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.example.com/api/spotify/1IJxbEXfgiKuRx6oXMX87e' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

CORS on project B is set to `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`.

Am I missing an additional setting or something?

Comment: Did you eventually found a solution? I'm having the same issue right now

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have following setup part of the the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/), particularly for MIDDLEWARE:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

> CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise’s WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses.

`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` have been renamed to `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` in newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for the response Xavier! I should've put it that in my original question but my middlwares are in the correct order and renaming to CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS hasn't fixed anything.

Comment: I remember that I've got a similar issue when I've added a trailing slash or not when I called my endpoint (url + / ). Django rejected my request because my URL was not defined in my urls.py because I've forgot this trailing slash.

Comment: Tried it and still no dice. May I know what versions of Django/django-cors-headers you're using?